# How to append/concat a string after a comma on a comma-separated value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have column which stores values separated by a comma. It's something like this:

```
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| breakfast_id | breakfast_english_menu                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|            1 | Canned Orange Juice- Can of 5 to 7 oz, Oatmeal- ½ T, Almonds - (12 almonds), Milk with Coffee or Milk with Chocolate (1T.) (Only one)                                                                                                     |
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and so I would like to add a string after each comma at the beginning of a 'new value'.  It would be something like

```
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| breakfast_id | breakfast_english_menu                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|            1 | Canned Orange Juice- Can of 5 to 7 oz, [HI]Oatmeal- ½ T, [HI]Almonds - (12 almonds), [HI]Milk with Coffee or Milk with Chocolate (1T.) (Only one)                                                                                                     |
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Any help or tip is welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have only a simple pattern use `REPLACE`

> ```
> SELECT REPLACE('ned Orange Juice- Can of 5 to 7 oz, Oatmeal- ½ T, Almonds - (12 almonds), Milk with Coffee or Milk with Chocolate (1T.) (Only one)',', ',', [HI]')
> ```
>
> ```
> | REPLACE('ned Orange Juice- Can of 5 to 7 oz, Oatmeal- ½ T, Almonds - (12 almonds), Milk with Coffee or Milk with Chocolate (1T.) (Only one)',', ',', [HI]') |
> | :----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | ned Orange Juice- Can of 5 to 7 oz, [HI]Oatmeal- ½ T, [HI]Almonds - (12 almonds), [HI]Milk with Coffee or Milk with Chocolate (1T.) (Only one)              |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=714a30fc96d21aef5ab366eabeb9e9a7)*

For more complicated patterns, you would use regular expressions to find and replace.

If need be, you can nest `REPLACE` comands one in another to repace more than one strintg